# Transforming a linear constraint.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, linear-programming

I have two variables $x$, and $y$. That are related by $Bx=y$. There is also a linear inequality constraint on $x$: $Ax \leq b$. Is it possible to write down the feasible set of $y$ as a linear inequality constraint? How would I do this? I also know that the columns of $A$ are linearly independent, but I don't have any such condition on $B$.

Comment: In your question, is $b = B$?

Comment: No, sorry if it wasn't clear. $b$ is a vector and is just the rhs of the inequality on $x$. $B$ is a matrix that maps $x$ to $y$.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179282/mathcalh-polyhedron-under-a-linear-map